# Regex for both inner and outer matches

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex that will handle the following:

```
The SDK supports Version {old}{android}10.0{/android}{ios}14.4.2{/ios}{/old}{new}{android}11.0{/android}{ios}14.5{/ios}{/new}.
```

What I am looking for is the ability to capture all the followings in one regex match:

```
{android}10.0{/android}
{ios}14.4.2{/ios}
{android}11.0{/android}
{ios}14.5{/ios}

{old}{android}10.0{/android}{ios}14.4.2{/ios}{/old}
{new}{android}11.0{/android}{ios}14.5{/ios}{/new}
```

Currently, I have the following that only captures the first 4 that I have listed above:

```
{\w+?}[^{}]+?{\/\w+?}
```

If I want to also capture the last 2 in the above as well, how can I change the regex to match those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the words for the opening and the closing curly's, you can use capture groups with a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) to match the same that is captured in that group, not allowing to match up `{old}` with `{/new}`

Note that you don't have to match `\w+?` non greedy using a question mark, as the word characters do not match `}` and can not cross matching it. The same applies to `[^{}]+?`

```
{(old|new)}({(\w+)}[^{}]+{/\3})({(\w+)}[^{}]+{/\5}){/\1}
```

The pattern matches

- `{(old|new)}` Capture `old` or `new` in **group 1** between curly's
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `{(\w+)}` Capture 1+ word chars in **group 3** between curly's
  - `[^{}]+` Match 1+ times any char except `{` and `}`
  - `{/\3}` Match what is captured in group 3 between the closing curly's
- `)` Close group 2
- `(` Capture **group 4**

  - `{(\w+)}` Capture 1+ word chars in **group 5** between the curly's
  - `[^{}]+` Match 1+ times any char except `{` and `}`
  - `{/\5}` Match what is captured in group 5 between the closing curly's
- `)` Close group 5
- `{/\1}` Close the curly matching either old or new that was captured in group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TAK0iY/1)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"{(old|new)}({(\w+)}[^{}]+{/\3})({(\w+)}[^{}]+{/\5}){/\1}"

s = ("The SDK supports Version {old}{android}10.0{/android}{ios}14.4.2{/ios}{/old}{new}{android}11.0{/android}{ios}14.5{/ios}{/new}.\n")

matches = re.finditer(pattern, s)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n\n".format(match.group(), match.group(2), match.group(4)))
```

Output

```
{old}{android}10.0{/android}{ios}14.4.2{/ios}{/old}
{android}10.0{/android}
{ios}14.4.2{/ios}


{new}{android}11.0{/android}{ios}14.5{/ios}{/new}
{android}11.0{/android}
{ios}14.5{/ios}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to capture all:

```
{(old|new)}({\w+?}([^{}]+?){\/\w+?})+{\/(old|new)}
```

[Check how it works on Pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=%7B(old%7Cnew)%7D(%7B%5Cw%2B%3F%7D(%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B%3F)%7B%5C%2F%5Cw%2B%3F%7D)%2B%7B%5C%2F(old%7Cnew)%7D&test_string=%7Bold%7D%7Bandroid%7D10.0%7B%2Fandroid%7D%7Bios%7D14.4.2%7B%2Fios%7D%7B%2Fold%7D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Please note that the middle group will take the value of the last repeating pattern (in this case: `{ios}14.4.2{/ios}`) that overwrites previously captured `{android}10.0{/android}`.

If you want to capture them individually, I suggest you call out "tags" separately (I added names to the capturing groups for convenience):

```
{(old|new)}({android}(?P<android>[^{}]+?){\/android})({ios}(?P<ios>[^{}]+?){\/ios}){\/(old|new)}
```

[Check how it works on Pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=%7B(old%7Cnew)%7D(%7Bandroid%7D(%3FP%3Candroid%3E%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B%3F)%7B%5C%2Fandroid%7D)(%7Bios%7D(%3FP%3Cios%3E%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B%3F)%7B%5C%2Fios%7D)%7B%5C%2F(old%7Cnew)%7D&test_string=%7Bold%7D%7Bandroid%7D10.0%7B%2Fandroid%7D%7Bios%7D14.4.2%7B%2Fios%7D%7B%2Fold%7D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).